# Adobe Animate CC start animation on scroll

Tags: animation, adobe

I have incorportated an Animate CC animation into my website. I need to pause it until the user scrolls to that section. I've tried using waypoints.js and it animated the object in but the animation has already run it's course. Is there a way to pause it until it's in the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

https://github.com/UseAllFive/true-visibility

You could have this.stop(); at the very start of your animation and use:
`var my_element = document.getElementById('my-element');
//-- Returns true/false
my_element.isVisible(my_element);`

Assuming your canvas animation is called my_element, you can simply play the timeline if it returns true.